# "printf.c: no such file or directory" when gdb an assembly code from Professional Assembly Language Chapter04

Tags: c, gdb, libc, dynamic-library

I've compiled `cpuid2.s` to `cpuid2.o` by `as cpuid2.s -o cpuid2.o -gstabs`

Firstly I linked it by `ld -o cpuid2 cpuid2.o -lc` but
a message says `./cpuid2:no such file or directory` when I executed it
(which is due to having not use dynamic linker, says the book)

So I linked it by `ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cpuid2 cpuid2.o -lc`
then executed it, however a SegmentationFault occurs:
when gdb it step by step, gdb says `printf.c:no such file or directory` at the line `call printf`

is it because I haven't install C's library(however I can run simple C programs with function in stdio.h)?

```
#cpuid2.s View the CPUID Vendor ID string using C library calls
.code32
.section .data
output:
   .asciz "The processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n"
.section .bss
   .lcomm buffer, 12
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
   movl $0, %eax
   cpuid
   movl $buffer, %edi
   movl %ebx, (%edi)
   movl %edx, 4(%edi)
   movl %ecx, 8(%edi)
   pushl $buffer
   pushl $output
   call printf
   addl $8, %esp
   pushl $0
   call exit
```

Comment: *is it because I haven't install C's library* Close. It is because you don't have the *source code*  of the C library. Normally you don't need it. You can also assume that the C library implementation for `printf` is very likely correct.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Code is text and should be included directly into the question. Just copy&paste it into the question and put a line containint 3 byckticks above and below it as I did with my edit

Comment: @Gerhardh Many thanks, I can't simply step into C library, haha. And I've post the code the way you said and it looks much better. However there's still a SegmentationFalult in the line second to last("pushl $0"),  and I can't understand why

Comment: I think you are using the wrong dynamic loader for your 32-bit code.

Comment: The 12-character cpuid string is not null-terminated, so you will need to either make the buffer longer (it is in BSS so the extra characters will be initialized to 0), or use `%.12s` to print no more than 12 characters.

Comment: @IanAbbott Sad that it still comes out with a SegmentationFault at line 21 and no output  of printf, whether I use "%.12s" or change buffer length to 13

Comment: Well I think you are mixing up 32-bit and 64-bit ABIs.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks a lot, It turned out that you are right, I rewrote it in 64-bit syntax and it runs well